# Converting text to numbers?

Tags: r

So I am trying to code gender as a dummy variable. However, the data has gender coded as "1.Male" and "2.Female" (rather than 1=Male and 2=Female) I just want to recode it so it comes out as 1's and 2's

```
df$men <- car::recode(df$gender_respondent_x, "1=1; 2=0; else=NA")
table(df$men, df$gender_respondent_x, useNA = "ifany")

#       1. Male 2. Female
#  <NA>    2845      3069
```

Comment: `df$men <- ifelse(df$gender_respondent_x == "1. Male", 1, 2)`

Comment: Or `match(df$gender_respondent_x, c("1. Male", "2.Female"))`

Answer (score 0):

I think `extract_numeric()` from `tidyr` package is very useful.

```
library(tidyr)
table(extract_numeric(df$gender_respondent_x))
```

This function literally extract only digits from strings. I hope you find this helpful. Check out [this official document](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/extract_numeric.html) for details.